# Parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) - Haskell

Tags: haskell

It's silly, but I can not even solve the problem with spaces and tabs. Sometimes I think that the problem is not in me, but in Haskell. Why Python does not have the same problem?

My code is:

```
lookups :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
lookups x ys = do y <- ys
                  if fst y == x then return (snd y)
```

I have a error: `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)`. My code use only spaces.

Comment: As for “solving the problem with spaces and tabs” – just use _always exclusively_ spaces in Haskell, then there'll be no problem. Except if the problem is actually something else but indentation: like bheklilr said, it's in fact about the incomplete `if` `then` `else`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yep, I always use spaces. My IDE do it.

Comment: `If` and `then` are _always_ followed by an `else`. Haskell is _not_ imperative!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an `else` on your `if-then`.  All `if`s in Haskell must have `then` and `else`, otherwise the expression wouldn't always return a value.  In Haskell, all expression must return a value, so an `if-then` without an `else` isn't an expression, hence the parse error.  You need to decide what to do if `fst y /= x`:

```
lookups x ys = do y <- ys
                  if fst y == x
                    then return (snd y)
                    else ???
```

Comment: @David If you're coming from another language like Java or Python then yes, it isn't very intuitive, but you would still have an error in Java if you had `int func(int x) { if (x == 1) { return 2; } }`, since not all code paths return an `int` (I think my syntax is correct, I haven't written Java code in several years).  In Haskell it just doesn't parse without the `else` instead of throwing what amounts to a type error.

Comment: yeah, this code will not compile in `Java`. But message will give you more sense. Also, IDEA (best Java IDE) tell you about error with help static analyzer.